# read and write CSV files in Swift 3

Tags: swift, csv

I've seen different libraries like SwiftCSV, CSwiftV. AFAIK, they made for previous versions of swift.  I need a very simple realization for swift 3 : open file, read line, put into array; or open, write array to csv file, and that's it. Any help?

I have:

```
struct Data {
    var DataTime: Date = Date()
    var Price: Double = 0.0
}

func DatafromCSV(_ CSV: String, _ separator: String) -> [Data] {
    var x = [Data]()

    //open file, read line, put into array, close file

    return x
}

func DatatoCSV(_ CSV: String, _ separator: String) -> [Data] {
    var x = [Data]()

    //create file (erase data if exists, write data from array, close file

    return x
}
```

Comment: What about converting currently used lib to swift 3 by yourself, until official codebase is converted? Xcode provides pretty useful toolset for it.

Comment: Of course, I would do that, if I were a pro in swift. I tried to figure it out by myself, how to open files, but as far as I understand - there's no Apple realization. I'm new to swift and don't yet understand syntax of the language, I want very-very simple and reliable code.

Comment: my suggestion was to use Xcode to automatically convert lib files to swift 3 (if you are using opensource lib). So Xcode will do all the work for you, if not fail :) Details here: https://swift.org/migration-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSVImporter Framework, is very simple. You can add it to your projects following this link: https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter

```
static func extractFromCSV(){
       //the Path of the csv
       let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
       let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("name.csv")
       let path = destinationFileUrl.path
       let importer = CSVImporter<YourClassName?>(path: path,delimiter: ";")
       importer.importRecords{ recordValues -> Sede_Azienda? in
         //this piece of code is called for each row. You can access to each field with recordValues[x] and manage the data.
         return nil //or the object if you need it
       }
 }
```

This is asynchronous but this framework has also some sync methods. Look the documentation.

NB: YourClassName is the type of class of the returned object if you need it.